# Mark as successful action for builds in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, exit, jobs

I have a question to all the experienced Teamcity users out there.
I would like to exit out of a job based on a particular condition, but I do not want the status of the job as a failure. Is it possible to mark a job as successful even when you exit out of the job with an "exit code 1" or any pointers to achieve the same (exit out of a Teamcity job but mark the job as successful) through an alternative way is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TeamCity [service messages](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildStatus) to update build status, e.g. write to the output

```
##teamcity[buildStatus status='SUCCESS' text='{build.status.text} and then made green']
```

to get build status text concatenated with the `and then made green` string.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Command Line Build Step and you are using TeamCity 2017.2 then you can format stderr output as warning. Here is a documentation: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Command+Line