# TeamCity buildStatus service message not making success

Tags: teamcity

I'd like to halt remaining build steps at a step.

Both [official document](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildStatus) and [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49293992/361100) guide to do as below;

```
echo "##teamcity[buildStatus status='SUCCESS' text='Automation disabled']"
```

But to make halt builds at the step, I think I should put `exit 1` at the end. But this exit code gives red Failed result due to the Failure Condition; 'one of build steps exited with an error (e.g non-zero exit code)'

My trial is as below;

```
echo "##teamcity[buildStatus status='SUCCESS' text='Automation disabled']"
exit 1
```

how to make it show the *green success* result?

The document says 'You can also change the build status of a failing build to success' but not working as expected.

Both version 2017.2.3 and 2018.1.4 tested.

Answer (score 1):

On Microsoft ecosystem, `Exit Code 1`has a meaning of: `error` and not `true`.

you are simply setting up the status from `FAILURE` (possibly) to `SUCCESS` using the `message queue`, then setting it back to `FAILURE` by doing an `exit 1`.
If you switch your `exit 1` to `exit 0`, it should turn green.

**EDIT:**

Let's say you have x (A, B (...), F) `build steps` inside your build configuration.

You can define the `exit code 1` at the end of the build step `A`.

You can define the build step `B` only if `A`, the previous build step, is successful. (`Only if build status is successful`) - then, it will not run if the exit code is one.

You can define the build step `F` to run `Even if some of previous steps failed`.
And this build step will send to the message queue `echo "##teamcity[buildStatus status='SUCCESS' text='Automation disabled']"`

So, your build will be marked as a success, but your build step `B` will not be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `exit 0` did green result, but what I intended was to _SKIP_ rest of build steps. `exit 0` runs afterward.

Comment: I have improved my answer to describe how to skip build steps.